# RadioButton value Increment decrement using Java

Tags: java

this is a online exam system. if the answer is correct  marks increment by  1  it is work correctly at the same question second time select wrong answer i i need decrement the value

```
  int marks;
    String cor;
        public void answerCheck()
            {
                String answerAnswer="";

                if(r1.isSelected())
                {
                    answerAnswer = r1.getText();

                }

               else if(r2.isSelected())
                {
                    answerAnswer = r2.getText();

                }

                   else if(r3.isSelected())
                {
                    answerAnswer = r3.getText();

                }

                    else if(r4.isSelected())
                {

                    answerAnswer = r4.getText();

                }

                if(answerAnswer.equals(cor))
                {
                    marks = marks + 1;
                    String Marks = String.valueOf(marks);
                    txtc.setText(Marks);
                }
                else if(!answerAnswer.equals(cor))
                {
                     marks = marks - 1;
                    String Marks = String.valueOf(marks);
                    txtc.setText(Marks);

                }
                else
                {
                    marks =0;
                }

            }
```

i am loading all data from the database correct answer also i am loading
**Database Load**

```
public void Connection()
   {


             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/onlineex","root","");
               String query = "select * from questions";
       pst = con.prepareStatement(query);

             rs = pst.executeQuery();

                  while(rs.next())
            {     
                txtqu.setText(rs.getString("id"));
                txtques.setText(rs.getString("question"));
                r1.setText(rs.getString(3));
                r2.setText(rs.getString(4));
                r3.setText(rs.getString(5));
                r4.setText(rs.getString(6));
                 cor = rs.getString(7);
            }

             }
```

**i have a button call next**

```
 try
           {

            if(rs.previous())
            {   

                txtques.setText(rs.getString("question"));
                r1.setText(rs.getString(3));
                r2.setText(rs.getString(4));
                r3.setText(rs.getString(5));
                r4.setText(rs.getString(6));

            cor=rs.getString(7);
            }
            else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "This is first record of student");
                }
        answerCheck();
      }
```

i have button call previous

```
if(rs.next())
        {   

            txtques.setText(rs.getString("question"));
            r1.setText(rs.getString(3));
            r2.setText(rs.getString(4));
            r3.setText(rs.getString(5));
            r4.setText(rs.getString(6));

        cor=rs.getString(7);
        }
        else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "This is first record of student");
            }
    answerCheck();
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain your actual problem? The code looks ok from a glance (i see the increment & decrement parts). Is it not doing what you want? Can you explain more clearly what it does, and what it should do? I feel like you're missing the storage of marks in Database but I'm unsure if that is what you want

Comment: this is mock up exam system . which has two button next and prevois i saw the screen shot above. if i select correct answer marks increment by 1   after the click  the next button. after the prevois button and changes the answer as wrong it is mark become 1 not changed 0.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there is a Logical error in last else which will never execute because either answer is correct or wrong there is no third condition.

```
String cor;
    public void answerCheck()
        {
            String answerAnswer="";

            if(r1.isSelected())
            {
                answerAnswer = r1.getText();

            }

           else if(r2.isSelected())
            {
                answerAnswer = r2.getText();

            }

               else if(r3.isSelected())
            {
                answerAnswer = r3.getText();

            }

                else if(r4.isSelected())
            {

                answerAnswer = r4.getText();

            }

            if(answerAnswer.equals(cor))
            {
                marks = marks + 1;
                String Marks = String.valueOf(marks);
                txtc.setText(Marks);
            }
            else if(!answerAnswer.equals(cor) || ((r1.isSelected() || 
                    r2.isSelected() || r3.isSelected() || r4.isSelected()))
            {
                 marks = marks - 1;
                String Marks = String.valueOf(marks);
                txtc.setText(Marks);

            }

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213822/discussion-on-answer-by-coder1-radiobutton-value-increment-decrement-using-java).